# Multiple Camel Proxys in same camel context

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix

I am trying to invoke a direct endpoint using camel proxy and a Java Interface. I exposed this interface as OSGI service to another bundle and accessing the interface in that bundle. Everything worked fine and now i got a requirement  to invoke another direct endpoint based on certain conditions in same camel context using same interface. How can i do this?

```
    Camel routes:
    <camelContext id="cContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <proxy id="camelProxyService"
               serviceInterface="com.xxx.CamelProxyService"
               serviceUrl="direct:endpoint1" />

    <route id="route1">
       <from uri="direct:endpoint1" />
       <to uri="seda:a" />
    </route>

    <route id="route2">
      <from uri="direct:endpoint2" />
       <to uri="seda:b" />
    </route>
    </camelContext>

    <service ref="camelProxyService" interface="com.xxx.CamelProxyService"/>


    public interface CamelProxyService {

        public void method1(String str);

        public void method2(String str);
    }

    How can i define the interface as camel proxy in camel context and mention method names to call different direct endpoints? Any help is appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<proxy id="camelProxyService"
           serviceInterface="com.uday.camel.proxy.CamelProxyService"
           serviceUrl="direct:endpoint1" />
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="direct:endpoint1"/>
    <camel:process ref="conditionProcess"/>
    <camel:choice>
        <camel:when>
            <camel:header>${condition}=method1</camel:header>
            <camel:to uri="seda:a"/>
        </camel:when>
        <camel:otherwise>
            <camel:to uri="seda:b"/>
        </camel:otherwise>
    </camel:choice>
    <camel:stop/>
</camel:route>
```

public class ConditionProcess implements Processor {

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    BeanInvocation invocation = exchange.getIn().getBody(BeanInvocation.class);
    String methodName = invocation.getMethod().getName();
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("condition", methodName);
    System.out.println("Method "+methodName);
}
```

}